# Automated graceful reload of gunicorn in production

Tags: bash, deployment, shell-scripting, gunicorn

I have an automated deployment workflow that pushes code out to my production servers and triggers database migrations, static file updates, etc. Problem is, gunicorn doesn't automatically reload code changes without the development option `--reload`, which they recommend not using in production. Instead the instruction is to send an `HUP` signal to the `masterpid`. Problem is, I don't know how to retrieve the `masterpid` in an automated script, though it is easy enough to do manually.

How can I retrieve the `materpid` value for the gunicorn systemd process in a bash script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following to the systemd service file for `gunicorn`, or add it as an override:

```
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

You can then reload with `systemctl reload gunicorn`.

Comment: Or better yet, `gunicorn@application`....

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not sure what you mean by that... if it is, in fact, a better solution, please describe it in an answer and I'll select it if it is indeed better.

Comment: The answer is too brief. Possible to explain?

Answer (score 4):

More detailed explanation for editing your gunicorn service file (based on the answer of @jordanm):

Edit your service file `/etc/systemd/system/my_task.service` or a similar path

```
[Unit]
Description=My task running runicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
User=my_user
# [...]
ExecStart=/home/my_user/my_task/.venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:my_task.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID # <------ add this line

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save it, then run the following to reload the config

```
sudo systemctl enable my_task
```

Then you can run the following to gracefully restart your gunicorn service (this should be run in your deploy script)

```
sudo systemctl reload my_task gunicorn restart
```

---

If you don't run the `systemctl enable my_task` command, you might get the following error:

> Failed to reload my_task.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit my_task.service.
>   See system logs and 'systemctl status my_task.service' for details.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an answer for similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902930/how-do-i-restart-gunicorn-hup-i-dont-know-masterpid-or-location-of-pid-file/60833629#60833629). It could be an easier solution compared to the accepted answer, specially in cases `gunicorn` is not installed system-wide.

#### in case link did not work

the one liner below, gets the job perfectly done:

```
kill -HUP `ps -C gunicorn fch -o pid | head -n 1`
```

#### Explanation

`pc -C gunicorn` only lists the processes with `gunicorn` command, i.e., workers and **master** process. Workers are children of **master** as can be seen using `ps -C gunicorn fc -o ppid,pid,cmd`. We only need the pid of the **master**, therefore `h` flag is used to remove the first line which is PID text. Note that, `f` flag assures that `master` is printed above workers.

The correct procedure is to send `HUP` signal only to the **master**. In this way `gunicorn` is gracefully restarted, *only the workers, not master, are recreated*.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/441173)

Comment: @DaveM updated answer